# CSS dropdown menu disappears on page refresh

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

So, I have a strange error with my CSS dropdown menu.
The website I'm designing has a standard index.html as the homepage which contains two main parts:

- menu header at the top.
- iframe in the middle where all selected pages are loaded.

The user hovers over one of the four menu categories at the top, a dropdown then appears with all the sub-options and when clicked it will load that page into the frame.

The problem I have, and this is ONLY in Chrome as Firefox & IE work fine, if the user refreshes the page or presses F5, when hovering over one of the menu categories all the sub-options have disappeared. Yet, the strange thing is that the links are still active so even though you cannot see any writing if the user clicks in the area where it should be, the page still loads into the frame.

This has only happened since I changed the homepage to use an iframe instead of just opening the page directly, as the menu content opens over the top of the frame. The CSS that covers these menus is shown below:

```
.menu-head-td, .menu-item {
transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.menu-head-td:hover {
    background-color:#37465D;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer; 
}


.menu {
    cursor:pointer;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.menu-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#37465D;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity:0.9;
    left:0px;
    top:93px;
}
.menu-item:hover {
    background-color:#3466B1;
}

.menu:hover .menu-content {
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

The menus are all made up of simple  and  tags, no javascript or anything like that. I should mention that if the user clicks the address bar and just presses enter, it seems to reload the homepage again and the menus are all normal again. Strange hey?!

Comment: It would be bit easier to help you if you could transfer your code into an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might it be possible that you watching the website with a laptop that contains touch? I know out of experience that Chrome sees this kind of devices as touch devices even when you do not use any touch gestures.  Therefore it might be the case that the hover in your case does not work as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found an answer, a user on another site suggested moving around the order in which the browser detects the font files listed in the CSS file.

Originally the *.ttf file was listed above the *.woff file, I rearranged them so that the *.woff file is detected first and it works perfectly. Perhaps Chrome struggles with TTF files.